# How to add Class to existing DLL

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am querying for while that how to add class in existing dll? i want to know is it possible if yes then how or any alternative for it?

thanks

Comment: Why do you need to add a class to an existing dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not change the code of the library you have then you can do couple of things.

- Generate code of library with some tool like [reflector.net](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and add new class in it.
- Add class in new dll and use some tool like [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), to merge these two dlls to get one.

*Note:* Both options wont work if the dll has strong name, you can read more in this MSDN article [Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *Generate code of library and add new class in it.* You should explain what you mean with this... Use IlSpy/other tool to decompile the dll? And note that both options won't work if the dll has strong naming

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this

1. Create a new ClassLibrary project.
2. Reference the DLL.
3. Write your new class and methods.
4. Make a new DLL out of it.

Isn't that what we all do when we reference 3rd party DLLs?